# Windows Service Bus Check Performance Counters

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus, azureservicebus

I want to develop a C# application. The application should check performance coutners on the Service Bus like

• The current number of messages per Topic / Queue

• The average processing time per message

• The number of messages processed per unit of time

I saw that there is a package for C# available named "Service Bus 1.0 for Windows Server" but with that you can't check performance counters. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please, do not include a languge tag in a title unless it wouldn't made sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a problem for the Windows Azure Management Libraries. A c# library that microsoft is releasing soon. You can get it from Nuget as prerelease at this point.

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.ServiceBus
```

and heres some code that will get you started.

```
using (var azure = new ServiceBusManagementClient(...))
{
   var allYourServiceNamespaces = await azure.Namespaces.ListAsync();
   var topic = azure.Topics.Get(allYourServiceNamespaces.First().Name,"topicname").Topic;


}
```

I am not sure if you can get the processing time per message ect, but it can give you the same information you can get from the REST API.

Comment: Hello,

I tried the Windows Azure Monitoring Services Management Library, which is part of the Managment Libaries:
http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring/

I tried to check performance counters with the help of the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.dll. But I looked at the online documentation and I found out that you can use this library only if you use the whole Windows Azure Suit, am I right? We only use the Service Bus for Windows Server.

Best regards and thank you for your help

Comment: I have not tried that. The library is only a wrapper around the rest api and if microsoft list that the rest api can only be used for the Azure Pack, then I guess thats the truth. Just wanted to point you in the direction of the management libraries as they are an easy way to get the information (if its accessible).